# Major errors with pgf plots and clashes with biblatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, biblatex

I'm trying to make some simple graphs using `pgfplots`. However, there seems to be a number of error messages that baffle me as I can not find anything wrong with the script. This figure, containing a number of subfigures also affects the compilation of by bibliography. I get error messages saying my `.bib` file has errors, however when I delete this figure from my script these errors don't exist. When I run it with a .bib file for references I get a bunch of `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup` errors that point to lines in the `.bib` file which are supposedly incorrect, but they are fine. Can someone help me? I can't find any precedents in stack that help.

I've provided below the code I used for the figure as well as the preamble of my thesis. If you run it you will see that there are a number of runaway argument errors that don't make sense as well as a number of `Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating` errors that I can't understand. If you could give me a breakdown of where the error is that would be great.

Thanks for

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{texshade}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs,rotating,adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf,font=scriptsize,labelfont=normalsize}
\usepackage{rotating}
\PassOptionsToPackage{export}{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{gensymb} %greek letters
\graphicspath{{images/}{chapter01_images/}{chapter02_images/}{chapter03_images/}}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm,bindingoffset=6mm,total={170mm,257mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric, sorting=nyt, citestyle=authoryear ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{draft_ref.bib}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\sidecaptionvpos{figure}{c}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[CO,CE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{Thesis Title}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}[h]{1\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=south west,
        legend cell align={left},
        ylabel = Ratio(340/380),
        xlabel = Sodium(mM),
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=20,
        xtick={-5,0,5,10,15},
        xlabels={
        0,
        5,
        10,
        20};
        ytick={0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
        height=6cm,
        width=10cm,
        grid=none,
        title = {Sodium Standard Curve},
    ]
    \addplot table[fill=red!25,mark=none, row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {
        X Y\\
        0 0.611\\
        5 0.915\\
        10 1.265\\
        15 1.685\\
    };
\addlegendentry{y=0.729x + 0.5731, R$^2$=0.93885}
    \addplot+[fill=blue!25,only marks,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit,] coordinates {
        (0,0.611) +- (0.027,0.027)
        (5,0.915) +- (0.035,0.035)
        (10,1.265) +- (0.028,0.028)
        (15,1.685) +- (0.045,0.045)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[]{1\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=south west,
        legend cell align={left},
        ylabel = Ratio(340/380),
        xlabel = Sodium(mM),
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=20,
        xtick={-5,0,5,10,15},
        xlabels={
        0,
        5,
        10,
        20};
        ytick={0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
        height=6cm,
        width=10cm,
        grid=none,
        title = {HEK293 Nav1.7 stable cell line},
    ]
    \addplot table[fill=red!25,mark=none, row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {
        X Y\\
        0 0.3\\
        5 0.3\\
        10 0.3\\
        15 0.3\\
    };
    \addplot+[fill=red!25,only marks,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit,] coordinates {
        (2,12.16) +- (0.0)
        (0,10.57) +- (0.0)
        (0,10.4) +- (0.0)
        (148,10.35) +- (0.0)
        (0,9.22) +- (0.0)
        (26,9.54) +- (0.0)
        (0,9.18) +- (0.0)
        (3,9.06) +- (0.0)
        (0,8.86) +- (0.0)
        (17,8.39) +- (0.0)
        (0,7.84) +- (0.0)
        (74,7.34) +- (0.0)
        (34,7.13) +- (0.0)
        (35,6.96) +- (0.0)
        (18,6.81) +- (0.0)
        (76,6.75) +- (0.0)
        (6,6.46) +- (0.0)
        (446,6.38) +- (0.0)
        (143,6.11) +- (0.0)
        (447,5.98) +- (0.0)
        (146,6.02) +- (0.0)
        (55,5.99) +- (0.0)
        (12,5.99) +- (0.0)
        (447,5.98) +- (0.0)
        (16,5.63) +- (0.0)
        (0,5.54) +- (0.0)
        (38,5.54) +- (0.0)
        (172,5.59) +- (0.0)
        (458,5.66) +- (0.0)
        (4,5.39) +- (0.0)
        (66,5.40) +- (0.0)
        (172,5.59) +- (0.0)
        (458,5.66) +- (0.0)
        (4,5.39) +- (0.0)
        (66,5.40) +- (0.0)
        (230,5.28) +- (0.0)
        (13,5.20) +- (0.0)
        (68,5.23) +- (0.0)
        (230,5.28) +- (0.0)
        (448,512) +- (0.0)
        (69,5.06) +- (0.0)
        (94,4.96) +- (0.0)
        (129,4.94) +- (0.0)
        (342,4.96) +- (0.0)
        (448,5.12) +- (0.0)
        (13,5.02) +- (0.0)
        (0,4.72) +- (0.0)
        (7,4.66) +- (0.0)
        (258,4,43) +- (0.0)
        (521,4.38) +- (0.0)
        (0,4.31) +- (0.0)
        (24,4.41) +- (0.0)
        (227,4.15) +- (0.0)
        (257,4.14) +- (0.0)
        (314,4.06) +- (0.0)
        (6,4.22) +- (0.0)
        (10,4.23) +- (0.0)
        (113,4.15) +- (0.0)
        (118,4.12) +- (0.0)
        (201,3.98) +- (0.0)
        (187,3.98) +- (0.0)
        (108,4.01) +- (0.0)
        (83,3.89) +- (0.0)
        (35,3.77) +- (0.0)
        (132,3.62) +- (0.0)
        (278,8.59) +- (0.0)
        (196,3.32) +- (0.0)
        (227,3.27) +- (0.0)
        (331,3.36) +- (0.0)
        (46,3.07) +- (0.0)
        (97,3.19) +- (0.0)
        (196,3.32) +- (0.0)
        (227,3.27) +- (0.0)
        (502,3.27) +- (0.0)
        (46,3.07) +- (0.0)
        (120,2.88) +- (0.0)
        (385,2.98) +- (0.0)
        (487,3.08) +- (0.0)
        (554,3.15) +- (0.0)
        (560,3.12) +- (0.0)
        (570,3.14) +- (0.0)
        (704,2.97) +- (0.0)
        (747,3.00) +- (0.0)
        (1128,2.73) +- (0.0)
        (1415,2.66) +- (0.0)
        (1444,2.60) +- (0.0)
        (120,2.88) +- (0.0)
        (385,2.98) +- (0.0)
        (487,3.08) +- (0.0)
        (554,3.14) +- (0.0)
        (522,2.98) +- (0.0)
        (644,2.88) +- (0.0)
        (684,2.83) +- (0.0)
        (704,2.97) +- (0.0)
        (684,2.83) +- (0.0)
        (11,2.73) +- (0.0)
        (16,2.77) +- (0.0)
        (120,2.88) +- (0.0)
        (497,2.94) +- (0.0)
        (522,2.92) +- (0.0)
        (53,2.53) +- (0.0)
        (165,2.42) +- (0.0)
        (470,2.41) +- (0.0)
        (503,2.67) +- (0.0)
        (581,2.70) +- (0.0)
        (49,2.18) +- (0.0)
        (421,2.35) +- (0.0)
        (470,2.41) +- (0.0)
        (510,2.27) +- (0.0)
        (527,2.34) +- (0.0)
        (540,2.33) +- (0.0)
        (549,2.34) +- (0.0)
        (553,2.37) +- (0.0)
        (584,2.44) +- (0.0)
        (641,2.39) +- (0.0)
        (717,2.25) +- (0.0)
        (646,2.23) +- (0.0)
        (611,2.15) +- (0.0)
        (622,2.11) +- (0.0)
        (35,2.35) +- (0.0)
        (165,2.24) +- (0.0)
        (421,2.35) +- (0.0)
        (510,2.27) +- (0.0)
        (611,2.15) +- (0.0)
        (622,2.11) +- (0.0)
        (822,1.99) +- (0.0)
        (649,1.69) +- (0.0)
        (554,1.96) +- (0.0)
        (230,2.22) +- (0.0)
        (221,2.14) +- (0.0)
        (229,1.97) +- (0.0)
        (35,2.23) +- (0.0)
        (49,2.18) +- (0.0)
        (230,2.22) +- (0.0)
        (221,2.14) +- (0.0)
        (229,1.97) +- (0.0)
        (49,2.18) +- (0.0)
        (47,2.01) +- (0.0)
        (2,1.93) +- (0.0)
        (21,1.74) +- (0.0)
        (42,1.56) +- (0.0)
        (646,2.23) +- (0.0)
        (2,1.93) +- (0.0)
        (12,1.93) +- (0.0)
        (47,2.01) +- (0.0)
        (142,1.79) +- (0.0)
        (42,1.59) +- (0.0)
        (38,1.51) +- (0.0)
        (0,1.21) +- (0.0)
        (503,1.50) +- (0.0)
        (533,1.48) +- (0.0)
        (646,1.25) +- (0.0)
        (571,1.00) +- (0.0)
        (526,1.15) +- (0.0)
        (516,0.57) +- (0.0)
        (511,0.51) +- (0.0)
        (0,0.06) +- (0.0)
        (1673,0.86) +- (0.0)
        (1683,0.72) +- (0.0)
    };
    \addplot table[fill=blue!25,mark=none, row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {
        X Y\\
        0 0.4\\
        5 0.4\\
        10 0.4\\
        15 0.4\\
    };
    \addplot+[fill=blue!25,only marks,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit,] coordinates {
        (0,0.611) +- (0.027,0.027)
        (5,0.915) +- (0.035,0.035)
        (10,1.265) +- (0.028,0.028)
        (15,1.685) +- (0.045,0.045)
    };
    \addplot table[fill=green!25,mark=none, row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {
        X Y\\
        0 0.5\\
        5 0.5\\
        10 0.5\\
        15 0.5\\
    };
    \addplot+[fill=green!25,only marks,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit,] coordinates {
        (0,0.611) +- (0.027,0.027)
        (5,0.915) +- (0.035,0.035)
        (10,1.265) +- (0.028,0.028)
        (15,1.685) +- (0.045,0.045)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[]{1\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=south west,
        legend cell align={left},
        ylabel = Ratio(340/380),
        xlabel = Sodium(mM),
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=20,
        xtick={-5,0,5,10,15},
        xlabels={
        0,
        5,
        10,
        20};
        ytick={0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
        height=6cm,
        width=10cm,
        grid=none,
        title = {Dorsal Root Ganglia},
    ]
    \addplot table[fill=red!25,mark=none, row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {
        X Y\\
        0 0.3\\
        5 0.3\\
        10 0.3\\
        15 0.3\\
    };
    \addplot+[fill=red!25,only marks,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit,] coordinates {
        (0,0.611) +- (0.027,0.027)
        (5,0.915) +- (0.035,0.035)
        (10,1.265) +- (0.028,0.028)
        (15,1.685) +- (0.045,0.045)
    };
    \addplot table[fill=blue!25,mark=none, row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {
        X Y\\
        0 0.4\\
        5 0.4\\
        10 0.4\\
        15 0.4\\
    };
    \addplot+[fill=blue!25,only marks,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit,] coordinates {
        (0,0.611) +- (0.027,0.027)
        (5,0.915) +- (0.035,0.035)
        (10,1.265) +- (0.028,0.028)
        (15,1.685) +- (0.045,0.045)
    };
    \addplot table[fill=green!25,mark=none, row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {
        X Y\\
        0 0.5\\
        5 0.5\\
        10 0.5\\
        15 0.5\\
    };
    \addplot+[fill=green!25,only marks,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit,] coordinates {
        (0,0.611) +- (0.027,0.027)
        (5,0.915) +- (0.035,0.035)
        (10,1.265) +- (0.028,0.028)
        (15,1.685) +- (0.045,0.045)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\caption[]{}
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, after having downloaded `pgf-pie.sty` (which you forgot to mention) and removing the `xlabels={...};` (which ends with a `;` and I don't think that's good) the compilation takes forever, i.e. does not terminate. I might well be using a different version of `pgf-pie.sty`, impossible to tell since you're not saying where you got yours from.

Comment: Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Comment: The MWE hangs for me and consequently does not show a problem with tzhe bibliography. Is really all of the code necessary to reproduce the problem? Do you need all the packages in the preamble and all the diagrams for that? Did you check that the MWE gives the same errors as your main document? Are you sure you are not using modified non-standard versions of certain files?

Comment: I included all the code as I really can't find the error and I thought that maybe it was something I had included or excluded in the pramble.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what's going on with the bibliography, but I will note that there are a couple of errors in your `pgfplots` code. First of all, you have written

```
xlabels={
..
};
```

when you should have written (I assume)

```
xticklabels={
..
},
```

Wrong key name, and semicolon instead of comma.

The other problem is that you're specifying errors in the wrong way in one of the plots (the one with the very long coordinate list). You must provide *both* x- and y-errors, even if you're only using the y. That is, you need

```
(x,y) +- (e_x, e_y)
```

not just

```
(x,y) +- (e_x)
```

For that plot all the errors are zero though, so you could consider removing the error specifications altogether.

Another problem in that same plot is that one of the coordinates has two commas, it says

```
(258,4,43)
```

which should probably be

```
(258,4.43)
```

Having fixed all of that, I did get a dimension too large error, seemingly because some of the points are far outside the specified range of the `axis`. Adding `restrict y to domain={-0:2}` to the settings of the `\addplot` in question fixed that problem here.

A couple of other points: The legend entry in the first axis should be `\addlegendentry{$y=0.729x + 0.5731$, $R^2=0.93885$}` I think. And if you're not planning to add captions to each subfigure, then you don't need the `subfigure` environments at all. I would consider a `groupplot` environment from the `groupplots` library of `pgfplots`.

Finally, regarding your preamble, note that you're loading the `caption` package twice. (You could also skip the explicit loading of `graphicx`, `color`, `pgfplots` and `tikz`, because `pgfplotstable` loads `pgfplots`, which loads `tikz`, and `tikz` in turn loads `graphicx` and `color`.)

Complete code, with the preamble containing only the necessary bits. Screenshot of output below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} % you might have to change version number if your version of pgfplots is older
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[h]{1\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=south west,
        legend cell align={left},
        ylabel = Ratio(340/380),
        xlabel = Sodium(mM),
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=20,
        xtick={-5,0,5,10,15},
        xticklabels={
        0,
        5,
        10,
        20},
        ytick={0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
        height=6cm,
        width=10cm,
        grid=none,
        title = {Sodium Standard Curve},
    ]
    \addplot table[fill=red!25,mark=none, row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {
        X Y\\
        0 0.611\\
        5 0.915\\
        10 1.265\\
        15 1.685\\
    };
\addlegendentry{$y=0.729x + 0.5731$, $R^2=0.93885$}
    \addplot+[fill=blue!25,only marks,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit,] coordinates {
        (0,0.611) +- (0.027,0.027)
        (5,0.915) +- (0.035,0.035)
        (10,1.265) +- (0.028,0.028)
        (15,1.685) +- (0.045,0.045)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[]{1\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=south west,
        legend cell align={left},
        ylabel = Ratio(340/380),
        xlabel = Sodium(mM),
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=20,
        xtick={-5,0,5,10,15},
        xticklabels={
        0,
        5,
        10,
        20},
        ytick={0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
        height=6cm,
        width=10cm,
        grid=none,
        title = {HEK293 Nav1.7 stable cell line},
    ]
    \addplot table[fill=red!25,mark=none, row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {
        X Y\\
        0 0.3\\
        5 0.3\\
        10 0.3\\
        15 0.3\\
    };
    \addplot+[fill=red!25,only marks,
               restrict y to domain={-0:2}, % <-- added this
               error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit,] coordinates {
        (2,12.16) +- (0,0)
        (0,10.57) +- (0,0)
        (0,10.4) +- (0,0)
        (148,10.35) +- (0,0)
        (0,9.22) +- (0,0)
        (26,9.54) +- (0,0)
        (0,9.18) +- (0,0)
        (3,9.06) +- (0,0)
        (0,8.86) +- (0,0)
        (17,8.39) +- (0,0)
        (0,7.84) +- (0,0)
        (74,7.34) +- (0,0)
        (34,7.13) +- (0,0)
        (35,6.96) +- (0,0)
        (18,6.81) +- (0,0)
        (76,6.75) +- (0,0)
        (6,6.46) +- (0,0)
        (446,6.38) +- (0,0)
        (143,6.11) +- (0,0)
        (447,5.98) +- (0,0)
        (146,6.02) +- (0,0)
        (55,5.99) +- (0,0)
        (12,5.99) +- (0,0)
        (447,5.98) +- (0,0)
        (16,5.63) +- (0,0)
        (0,5.54) +- (0,0)
        (38,5.54) +- (0,0)
        (172,5.59) +- (0,0)
        (458,5.66) +- (0,0)
        (4,5.39) +- (0,0)
        (66,5.40) +- (0,0)
        (172,5.59) +- (0,0)
        (458,5.66) +- (0,0)
        (4,5.39) +- (0,0)
        (66,5.40) +- (0,0)
        (230,5.28) +- (0,0)
        (13,5.20) +- (0,0)
        (68,5.23) +- (0,0)
        (230,5.28) +- (0,0)
        (448,512) +- (0,0)
        (69,5.06) +- (0,0)
        (94,4.96) +- (0,0)
        (129,4.94) +- (0,0)
        (342,4.96) +- (0,0)
        (448,5.12) +- (0,0)
        (13,5.02) +- (0,0)
        (0,4.72) +- (0,0)
        (7,4.66) +- (0,0)
        (258,4.43) +- (0,0)
        (521,4.38) +- (0,0)
        (0,4.31) +- (0,0)
        (24,4.41) +- (0,0)
        (227,4.15) +- (0,0)
        (257,4.14) +- (0,0)
        (314,4.06) +- (0,0)
        (6,4.22) +- (0,0)
        (10,4.23) +- (0,0)
        (113,4.15) +- (0,0)
        (118,4.12) +- (0,0)
        (201,3.98) +- (0,0)
        (187,3.98) +- (0,0)
        (108,4.01) +- (0,0)
        (83,3.89) +- (0,0)
        (35,3.77) +- (0,0)
        (132,3.62) +- (0,0)
        (278,8.59) +- (0,0)
        (196,3.32) +- (0,0)
        (227,3.27) +- (0,0)
        (331,3.36) +- (0,0)
        (46,3.07) +- (0,0)
        (97,3.19) +- (0,0)
        (196,3.32) +- (0,0)
        (227,3.27) +- (0,0)
        (502,3.27) +- (0,0)
        (46,3.07) +- (0,0)
        (120,2.88) +- (0,0)
        (385,2.98) +- (0,0)
        (487,3.08) +- (0,0)
        (554,3.15) +- (0,0)
        (560,3.12) +- (0,0)
        (570,3.14) +- (0,0)
        (704,2.97) +- (0,0)
        (747,3.00) +- (0,0)
        (1128,2.73) +- (0,0)
        (1415,2.66) +- (0,0)
        (1444,2.60) +- (0,0)
        (120,2.88) +- (0,0)
        (385,2.98) +- (0,0)
        (487,3.08) +- (0,0)
        (554,3.14) +- (0,0)
        (522,2.98) +- (0,0)
        (644,2.88) +- (0,0)
        (684,2.83) +- (0,0)
        (704,2.97) +- (0,0)
        (684,2.83) +- (0,0)
        (11,2.73) +- (0,0)
        (16,2.77) +- (0,0)
        (120,2.88) +- (0,0)
        (497,2.94) +- (0,0)
        (522,2.92) +- (0,0)
        (53,2.53) +- (0,0)
        (165,2.42) +- (0,0)
        (470,2.41) +- (0,0)
        (503,2.67) +- (0,0)
        (581,2.70) +- (0,0)
        (49,2.18) +- (0,0)
        (421,2.35) +- (0,0)
        (470,2.41) +- (0,0)
        (510,2.27) +- (0,0)
        (527,2.34) +- (0,0)
        (540,2.33) +- (0,0)
        (549,2.34) +- (0,0)
        (553,2.37) +- (0,0)
        (584,2.44) +- (0,0)
        (641,2.39) +- (0,0)
        (717,2.25) +- (0,0)
        (646,2.23) +- (0,0)
        (611,2.15) +- (0,0)
        (622,2.11) +- (0,0)
        (35,2.35) +- (0,0)
        (165,2.24) +- (0,0)
        (421,2.35) +- (0,0)
        (510,2.27) +- (0,0)
        (611,2.15) +- (0,0)
        (622,2.11) +- (0,0)
        (822,1.99) +- (0,0)
        (649,1.69) +- (0,0)
        (554,1.96) +- (0,0)
        (230,2.22) +- (0,0)
        (221,2.14) +- (0,0)
        (229,1.97) +- (0,0)
        (35,2.23) +- (0,0)
        (49,2.18) +- (0,0)
        (230,2.22) +- (0,0)
        (221,2.14) +- (0,0)
        (229,1.97) +- (0,0)
        (49,2.18) +- (0,0)
        (47,2.01) +- (0,0)
        (2,1.93) +- (0,0)
        (21,1.74) +- (0,0)
        (42,1.56) +- (0,0)
        (646,2.23) +- (0,0)
        (2,1.93) +- (0,0)
        (12,1.93) +- (0,0)
        (47,2.01) +- (0,0)
        (142,1.79) +- (0,0)
        (42,1.59) +- (0,0)
        (38,1.51) +- (0,0)
        (0,1.21) +- (0,0)
        (503,1.50) +- (0,0)
        (533,1.48) +- (0,0)
        (646,1.25) +- (0,0)
        (571,1.00) +- (0,0)
        (526,1.15) +- (0,0)
        (516,0.57) +- (0,0)
        (511,0.51) +- (0,0)
        (0,0.06) +- (0,0)
        (1673,0.86) +- (0,0)
        (1683,0.72) +- (0,0)
    };
    \addplot table[fill=blue!25,mark=none, row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {
        X Y\\
        0 0.4\\
        5 0.4\\
        10 0.4\\
        15 0.4\\
    };
    \addplot+[fill=blue!25,only marks,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit,] coordinates {
        (0,0.611) +- (0.027,0.027)
        (5,0.915) +- (0.035,0.035)
        (10,1.265) +- (0.028,0.028)
        (15,1.685) +- (0.045,0.045)
    };
    \addplot table[fill=green!25,mark=none, row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {
        X Y\\
        0 0.5\\
        5 0.5\\
        10 0.5\\
        15 0.5\\
    };
    \addplot+[fill=green!25,only marks,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit,] coordinates {
        (0,0.611) +- (0.027,0.027)
        (5,0.915) +- (0.035,0.035)
        (10,1.265) +- (0.028,0.028)
        (15,1.685) +- (0.045,0.045)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[]{1\textwidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
    \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=south west,
        legend cell align={left},
        ylabel = Ratio(340/380),
        xlabel = Sodium(mM),
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=20,
        xtick={-5,0,5,10,15},
        xticklabels={
        0,
        5,
        10,
        20},
        ytick={0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
        height=6cm,
        width=10cm,
        grid=none,
        title = {Dorsal Root Ganglia},
    ]
    \addplot table[fill=red!25,mark=none, row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {
        X Y\\
        0 0.3\\
        5 0.3\\
        10 0.3\\
        15 0.3\\
    };
    \addplot+[fill=red!25,only marks,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit,] coordinates {
        (0,0.611) +- (0.027,0.027)
        (5,0.915) +- (0.035,0.035)
        (10,1.265) +- (0.028,0.028)
        (15,1.685) +- (0.045,0.045)
    };
    \addplot table[fill=blue!25,mark=none, row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {
        X Y\\
        0 0.4\\
        5 0.4\\
        10 0.4\\
        15 0.4\\
    };
    \addplot+[fill=blue!25,only marks,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit,] coordinates {
        (0,0.611) +- (0.027,0.027)
        (5,0.915) +- (0.035,0.035)
        (10,1.265) +- (0.028,0.028)
        (15,1.685) +- (0.045,0.045)
    };
    \addplot table[fill=green!25,mark=none, row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]
    {
        X Y\\
        0 0.5\\
        5 0.5\\
        10 0.5\\
        15 0.5\\
    };
    \addplot+[fill=green!25,only marks,error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit,] coordinates {
        (0,0.611) +- (0.027,0.027)
        (5,0.915) +- (0.035,0.035)
        (10,1.265) +- (0.028,0.028)
        (15,1.685) +- (0.045,0.045)
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\caption[]{}
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]